# getState function is undefined in thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use thunk to get dispatch and getState functions into it
For some reason, dispatch in thunk is passed, but getState is not

```
export function prevDay(){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // getState === undefined
    dispatch(_prev( getState().day));
  }
}
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

I had do this:`onClick={props.prevDay()}`
No need to call this function. Need to:

```
onClick={props.prevDay}
```

It,s By bad(